# How do I view files in list form and view hidden files from unity home?

Tags: nautilus

Or otherwise how do I access file management preferences within unity?

Comment: Are you asking how to view hidden files from the Dash's files lens? I'm not sure what you mean by "unity home." That's not standard terminology.

Comment: @root45  To clarify, I am using Unity, then selecting the Home Folder, This opens Nautilus file manager with folders and files shown in icon view.  I would like list view and hidden files. I need to access "file management preferences" from Nautilus as I could previously do in gnome2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This opens Nautilus file manager with folders and files shown in icon view. I would like list view and hidden files.

If you just need to get to the settings for Nautilus, just go to Edit->Preferences. There you can select to show list view and hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the OP was unaware of the new detached menu bar in Unity. Threw me for a loop at first. If so, be aware that it is at the top of the screen, regardless of the size or placement of your file browser window, and that by default it auto-hides. Move your mouse to the top of the screen and it should appear.

Answer (score 0):

The lenses are not supposed to be a replacement for Nautilus. You use it to quickly find files you've used in the past. There's been discussion about making it search all files, but I don't think any decisions have been made about that. I personally feel that only files you've used should be displayed, since the only way the system can understand your interests, is by analyzing your actions.

Answer (score 0):

Or, You can easily use the "List View" in Unity by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.